# Quarkus native build fails after adding Open API / Swagger

Tags: apache-camel, openapi, smallrye, quarkus-native

I've recently added the `quarkus-smallrye-openapi` and `camel-quarkus-openapi-java` libraries to my Quarkus Camel app and have updated the endpoints with descriptions and parameters. The app runs fine in JVM mode but as soon as I'm trying to build the Quarkus native image I'm getting the following build error in the `Performing analysis...`  step:

```
Discovered unresolved method during parsing: io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema.enumAsRef()
```

(see full stack trace below).

Does anyone have any idea what could go wrong here? It wasn't quite clear to me from the Camel Quarkus OpenAPI example (see https://github.com/zhfeng/camel-quarkus-openapi-example) when a class needs to be registered for reflection via the `@RegisterForReflection`.

Sample REST endpoint:

```
        rest("/auth")
                .get()
                .description("Authenticate with the provided identifier.")
                .outType(AuthResponse.class)
                .param().name("identifier").type(header).description("The identifier of the request.").dataType("string").endParam()
                .responseMessage().code(200).message("Authentication was successful.").endResponseMessage()
                .responseMessage().code(500).message("Authentication was unsuccessful.").endResponseMessage()
```

```
Fatal error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error encountered while parsing io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(io.swagger.v3.core.converter.AnnotatedType, io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverterContext, java.util.Iterator) 
Parsing context:
   at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:125)
   at io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolve(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:97)
...
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema.enumAsRef(). This error is reported at image build time because class io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver is registered for linking at image build time by command line
        at parsing io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.shouldResolveEnumAsRef(ModelResolver.java:879)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2518)
 ...
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema.enumAsRef(). This error is reported at image build time because class io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver is registered for linking at image build time by command line
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.reportUnresolvedElement(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:333)
```

**UPDATE**
Removing the dependency on `camel-quarkus-openapi-java` passes the native build, however upon startup I get the error:
`Cannot find RestApiProcessorFactory in Registry or classpath (such as the camel-openapi-java component)`

This page: https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/3.0.x/reference/extensions/openapi-java.html
states that
`It’s the user’s responsibility to use @RegisterForReflection to register all model classes for reflection.`
But how would I know which classes require the annotation? I've added it to the `AuthResponse` without any success.

Here are the dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
    <!-- camel dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-bean</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-direct</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-caffeine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-jsonpath</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-log</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-platform-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-openapi-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- platform related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-kubernetes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkiverse.helm</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-helm</artifactId>
        <version>${helm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-kubernetes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-docker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quarkus-mock</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```